# How to change all localized Storyboard files at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, localization, storyboard

I have a localized storyboard file the old way (no use of "Base Internationalization"):
[image]

I changed the first file by adding a new ViewController. Now I realized, that these changes don't effect the other (localized) storyboard files.

**How can I edit all the storyboard files at once?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You have to change each file individually. That's why Apple created "Base Internationalization."

I used to deal with an OS X app with 23 translations and many nib files. Here's how the process looked prior to Base Internationalization:

- Work only in one language
- At some point close to release, localize
- Hope desperately that you will not need to touch localized resources until release
- Release
- Blow away your localized resource files and begin another round

It's not pretty. Again, that's why we have Base Internationalization. Now may be a good time to move over.

Comment: Thx rob! How time consuming is it to move over to base internationalization?

Comment: It depends on how complex your setup is, but generally you delete your storyboard localizations (except one), elevate one of them to the "base", and then create strings files for all the elements.